# If $ ab+bc+ca=3,$ then prove $2(a+b+c)+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge a\sqrt{4+5bc}+b\sqrt{4+5ca}+c\sqrt{4+5ab}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

**Question**
If $a,b,c\ge 0: ab+bc+ca=3,$ then prove $$2(a+b+c)+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge a\sqrt{4+5bc}+b\sqrt{4+5ca}+c\sqrt{4+5ab}$$
I've tried to use some known inequalities.

For example, by CBS we need to prove$$2(a+b+c)+3\sqrt[3]{abc}\ge \sqrt{a+b+c}\sqrt{4(a+b+c)+15abc}$$
but unfortunately, it is not true.

Is there a better estimate to clear the radical? I am looking some helps. Th

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Proof.**

The OP is obviously true when $abc=0.$

In case: $abc\neq 0,$ notice the equality$$a\sqrt{4+5bc}-2a=\frac{5abc}{\sqrt{4+5bc}+2}.$$
It remains to prove$$\frac{3}{5}\ge \sum_{cyc}\frac{\sqrt[3]{(abc)^2}}{\sqrt{4+5bc}+2}.$$
Set the substitution $(ab,bc,ca)\rightarrow(x,y,z).$ It implies $x,y,z>0: x+y+z=3.$

Hence, it is enough to prove$$\frac{3}{5\sqrt[3]{xyz}}\ge \frac{1}{\sqrt{5x+4}+2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5y+4}+2}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{5z+4}+2}.$$
Now, we can use two following estimates

- By Minkowski$$\sqrt{5x+4}+2\ge \frac{4+5\sqrt{x}}{3}+2=\frac{10+5\sqrt{x}}{3}.$$
- By AM-GM $$\left(\sqrt{x}+2\right)^2=x+4.\sqrt{x}+4\ge 9\sqrt[9]{x^3}=9\sqrt[3]{x}\implies \frac{\sqrt[3]{x}}{2+\sqrt{x}}\le \frac{2+\sqrt{x}}{9}.$$

Hence, we obtain $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{5x+4}+2}\le \frac{2+\sqrt{x}}{15\sqrt[3]{x}} .$$

Sum up cyclicly similar estimates, we get $$\left(2+\sqrt{x}\right).\sqrt[3]{yz}+\left(2+\sqrt{y}\right).\sqrt[3]{zx}+\left(2+\sqrt{z}\right).\sqrt[3]{xy}\le 9.$$
Also by AM-GM $\sqrt{x}\le \dfrac{x+1}{2};\sqrt[3]{yz}\le \dfrac{y+z+1}{3},$ and we will prove $$\sum\limits_{cyc}(x+5)(y+z+1)\le 54 \iff xy+yz+zx\le 3,$$which is true.

The proof is done. Equality holds at $a=b=c=1$ or $abc=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Let $a+b+c=3u$, $ab+ac+bc=3v^2$ and $abc=w^3$.

Thus, since by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}a\sqrt{4+5bc}\leq\sqrt{(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}a(4+5bc)}=$$
$$=\sqrt{3u(12u+15uw^3)}=3\sqrt{4u^2+5uw^3},$$  it's enough to prove that:
$$2u+w\geq\sqrt{4u^2+5uw^3}$$ or
$$4u+w\geq5uw^2,$$ which is true by AM-GM:
$$4u+w\geq5v^2\sqrt[5]{u^4w}=5\sqrt[5]{u^4v^{10}w}\geq5\sqrt[5]{u^4\cdot v^6\cdot uw^3\cdot w}=5\sqrt[5]{u^5v^6w^4}\geq5uw^2.$$

Comment: +1, when I search about $uvw,$ almost all documents mentioned that Michael Rozenberg (a.k.a arqady) was one of first mathematicians using this method and make it popular from at least 10 years ago. A powerful method is along with  great contributors! I am very appreciate it.

Comment: I accept the best answer.